# image returned from UIImagePickerController is smaller than original

Tags: ios, uiimage, size, uiimagepickercontroller

Im trying to get a full sized image from the photo library using `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`.
the returned UIImage size is 750 x 1001, but when i extract the image using Image Capture, it is actually 3264 x 2448, how can I get the real original image?

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233277/how-to-perform-square-cut-to-the-photos-in-camera-roll

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize the `UIImagePickerController` make sure to set `allowsEditing` property to `NO`, which would allow you to get the full-sized original image.

For an example, if you use:

```
self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
```

the resulting image you get in `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` from `info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]` will have it's size less than the actual original, like it's happening to you.

But if you set `self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;`, `UIImage` from `info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]` will be the exact same size as it's in the library.